# Create new CSV from existing CSV

Tags: perl, csv

I have managed to extract name and email addresses columns from from a CSV.

The email field is the only field that is always there. The name field can be blank, just a first name and sometimes a first name and last name. Like this:

```
Name, Email
Fred, fred@flinstones.com
Wilma Flinstone, wima@flintstones
,barny@rubble.com
```

What I would like to do is create a new CSV from the above that splits the name into first and last if possible. So the above would look like this:

```
First Name, Last Name, Email
Fred, ,fred@flinstones.com
Wilma, Flinstone, wima@flintstones
,,barny@rubble.com
```

How could I do this in Perl?

Comment: Consider what to do with `Pebbles Flintstone Rubble`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
($fullname, $email) = split(/,/);
($first, @last) = split(/ /, $fullname);
print join(',', $first, "@last", $email), "\n";
```

Comment: If the fullname has 3 or more words, e.g. "Anthony Michael Hall" or "J. R. R. Tolkien", this will not produce the right output.

Comment: Note: you can specify a limit for `split`, which would be a cleaner more efficient way to handle more than 2 word names: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html